# Make SoX not show output

Tags: windows, sox

I'm recording with SoX, and I want to make it not show output at all. When recording, it shows this output:

```
Input File     : 'default' (waveaudio)
Channels       : 2
Sample Rate    : 48000
Precision      : 16-bit
Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM

In:0.00% 00:00:00.68 [00:00:00.00] Out:28.7k [      |      ]        Clip:0
```

I tried setting verbosity to 0, but it has no effect. (I'm guessing it's meant for messages other than this.)

I don't just want to hide the output, which I could do easily; I want SoX to not generate it in the first place, for performance on a weak computer.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the `-q` option:

```
-q, --no-show-progress
     Run in quiet mode when SoX wouldn't otherwise do so. This is the opposite of the -S option.
```

Comment: What about removing just one part of the output, like the header? `grep` won't work.